# Storing existing local Terraform State to Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, devops, terraform-provider-aws

Trying to store an existing local terraform state file to the backend state storage S3. But running the terraform apply command throws error "Resource already exists".

Is there a method to successfully sync an existing .tfstate to AWS s3 ?

Answer (score 2):

After you setup the backend configuration code to an S3 bucket in Terraform 
run this command to push any local terraform state to AWS S3 using:

`terraform state push <path to your local  state>`

Comment: Tried running the $ terraform state push ~/path/tf.tfstate , but its throwing an error.

Comment: Failed to write state: cannot import state with lineage "xxxxxx-xxx-cxxx-bxxx-cbczzzzxxx90" over unrelated state with lineage "0y7gxx99-dg6e-103o-5679-109g1937a662"

Comment: Most probably it means you already have an existing initial "empty" tfstate in the backend. In my case (do only the following if you understand what you are doing), I (made a backup then) deleted the existing tfstate in the backend, removed the lock in DynamoDB, then did a `terraform state push`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Terraform backend has the variable name as "s3".

example :

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "s3-bukcet-name"
    key = "path-to-file"
    region = "region"
  }
}
```